# I am using NSSharingService in my macOS Swift app. Is there any way to make sure the default mail client is configured with a valid account?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nssharingservice

I am using [NSSharingService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssharingservice) to prepare an email with attachment for the user of my macOS app. My code is:

```
let emailService = NSSharingService.init(named: NSSharingService.Name.composeEmail)

if emailService.canPerform(withItems: [emailBody, zipFileURL]) {
   // email can be sent
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       emailService.perform(withItems: [emailBody, zipFileURL])
   }
} else {
      // email cannot be sent
      // Show alert with email address and instructions
      self.showErrorAlert(with: 2803)
}
```

This works correctly, but if the code is executed on a fresh system, Apple Mail will be opened asking the user to configure an email account. Some users may not understand what is going on in this situation. Is there a way to ascertain if the default Email Client is configured, so that I can inform the user if it is not ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Non sandboxed look at command "defaults read com.apple.mail". Sandboxed -> not really. You can check if iCloud is enabled (it also means account is configured). Alternative is private selectors -> not app store friendly. You shouldn't worry about this problem. Do the same as apple does for Finder + NSSharingService + Mail + no account

Comment: @Alfonso Tesauro , did you find any solution?